Justice League formation movie
This is a straight to DVD cartoon flick (if I am correct).
The scene I clearly remember is, Batman and Green Lantern go to Metropolis to talk Superman. Angry Superman starts attacking them. Green lantern says ".. is he trying to kill us" then Batman says something like "... not kill, just bruise, isn't that right Clark?", then Superman stops. Also there would be a portal sort of things (which people imagined to be a bomb) from which winged monsters spring out...

The movie you are looking for is Justice League: War.
The scene you describe occurs around 19:30 in the movie.

Green Lantern: This guy's gonna kill us!
Batman: No he won't.  You bruise but you don't kill.  Do you...Clark

And you are correct that it was a straight to video release.
